# MKMapView identifiers for certain city blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, apple-maps

I have a good bit of experience with `MKMapView`'s use of specific coordinates for locations, but is there a way to denote a certain range, such as a block of a street?  A way to say "the 5600 block of Main Street" or something similar, rather than a specific point?  I'd love it if you could even define the side of the street, but the block at least would be usable.

Or would you just need to define it using point-pairs, so "this block" is defined as the space between the `startOfBlockCoordinate` and `endOfBlockCoordinate` points?

I would offer code samples and such, but I legitimately don't know where to start.  Every time I try to do research on the topic, I end up getting results about "blocks" (like segments of code in Objective-C) and "blocks" (like preventing a user from doing something).

Comment: What do you want to do with these identifiers?  What's the goal?

Comment: The end result is sort of convoluted, but basically I want to build a database of street conditions by block.  "This block of Main Street has these properties, the next block of Main Street has these properties."  In the end I'd like to be able to highlight each block a different color based on the data associated with it, akin to how Google Maps highlights streets for different traffic conditions.  The trick is, I want to be able to associate the information with the block as a whole, rather than for a single point along that block.

Comment: You can define MKPolygon overlays for the blocks.